# What is this weed with ribbed stems and whorls of 1" to 2" long thin leaves?

Tags: identification, weed-control, weeds

Lately this weed has been growing all over my property. It is bright green, has tiny white flowers and kind of creeps along the ground as vines. It comes up fairly easily in clumps when I pull it, though I have no idea if I'm getting the roots when I do, but it's everywhere. I think it's spreading from an unmaintained property next to me.

[image: close up]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*Galium aparine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galium_aparine), which has many common names including goose grass, cleavers and robin-run-the-hedge. It's an annual weed, native to Europe and Asia that is now naturalized throughout the world.

Identifying characteristics are the whorled leafs around the ribbed stems, and the hairs that cover the leaves, stems and fruits. Those hairs are hooked, and can attach themselves to animal fur or clothing, which helps with spreading the seeds.

Control can be done by pulling the plants before they go to seed. The stems break easily (because it's part of their survival strategy), but if you break them at ground level, I haven't noticed them regrowing. They will also respond to herbicides if you're willing to use them.

Comment: Also called Catchweed Bedstraw http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn74154.html Infestations of the stuff vary greatly from year to year around here. Some years it's everywhere, others it can be hard to find.